# How to write Reg Expression to Ignore a file path

Tags: regex

I 've a File structure "solution/"

Need a reg exp to match all the files under "solution/"   Excluding .img files in the path "solution/tree/changes/sample.img"

I tried below it but of not worked

```
^solution\/tree\/changes\/((?!.img).)*$
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Specify the programming language. Regexps are different in some programming languages

Comment: We are actually providing an JSON input with regular expression, to copy files from the location.
Ex:  "^solution\/tree\/changes\/((?!.img).)*$"

Comment: `.img` matches any char followed with `img`. So, you need to escape the `.` to make it match a literal dot. You may also add `$` after `\.img` to make sure you only disallow it at the end of the string, and then your tempered greedy token will turn into a simple lookahead (`((?!.img).)*$` => `(?!.*\.img$).*`)

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention language, but this should work

```
^solution\/tree\/changes\/(?!.*\.img).*$
```

see regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/Y7znBy/1

Important! You need to set `multiline`flag

Comment: I dont understand. So this is not working for you?

Comment: 'My Exact requirement is I 've following file structure

solution/moon/
solution/tree/anomoly/
solution/tree/enquiry/
solution/tree/changes/space.img
solution/tree/changes/mine.txt

I've to parse a json file as input with regular expression to copy all the files in the above structure except solution/tree/changes/space.img

JSON Input which I've tried is

"^solution\/(?!tree\/).*\/*",
"^solution\/tree\/(?!changes\/).*\/*",
"^solution\/tree\/changes\/((?!.img).)*$"'

Answer (score 0):

@Fallenhero My Exact requirement is I 've following file structure

```
solution/moon/
solution/tree/anomoly/
solution/tree/enquiry/
solution/tree/changes/space.img
solution/tree/changes/mine.txt
```

I've to parse a json file as input with regular expression to copy all the files in the above structure except solution/tree/changes/space.img

JSON Input which I've tried but didn't work

```
"^solution\/(?!tree\/).*\/*",
"^solution\/tree\/(?!changes\/).*\/*",
"^solution\/tree\/changes\/((?!.img).)*$"
```

Could you please provide your ideas